# I'm new to javascript and I'm fetching JSON data from url, I'm only able to access data in success function, Am I missing something?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Here is the code :-

```
var quiz;
function startQuiz() {

     $.ajax({
        url: 'get_quiz/',
        cache: 'false',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: 'false',
        success: function(data) {
            quiz = data;
            alert(quiz[0].q);   // I'm able to access quiz here     

},   
    }    
);  
    }

startQuiz();

alert(quiz[0].q);   // Not able to access it here.
```

I'm not able to access quiz here, am I mission something?, Whats wrong with this?

Comment: The ajax callback happens at an arbitrary time in the future; you're trying to access it before it's been set.

Comment: Precisely. This is a typical race condition.

Comment: A race condition is something else entirely. Race conditions occur when you have threaded model, JavaScript has no threads, it has an event loop. Things never occur _simultaneously_ so a race is impossible.

Comment: Is there any way to access it? There is a JSON file at get_quiz/ URL. I want to access that data.

Comment: Yes of course, in the success function! :D All further handling of the data must be initiated from the success function.

Comment: It's a race between the mainline code and the ajax code--it's just a race whose outcome is very predictable.

Comment: No, I strongly disagree with your metaphor. The mainline code runs, then the success function runs, neatly waiting it's turn. There is shoving or jostling involved, it's strict and orderly. I suppose the only strange point is that the code doesn't run from top to bottom as it occurs in the file, but that is of no concern.

Comment: It's completely possible for the ajax callback to run before the rest of the mainline code does--it's just unlikely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ajax is assynchronous which can be an unfamiliar concept. Your code will run like this:

```
1. var quiz;
2. define function startQuiz;
3. call startQuiz;
4. do ajax call (and continue! don't block)
5. alert(quiz[0].q);    // Not able to access it here.
-- ajax call comes back
6. quiz = data;
7. alert(quiz[0].q);       // I'm able to access quiz here
```

Ajax is asynchronous, it doesn't block. This means that when you make the ajax call the callback doesn't actually get called until the ajax call returns, **it doesn't block** and wait. Instead the code will continue on.

Then later when the ajax call returns the data, your callback function will be executed.

Javascript does this by means of an event loop.

See it like this: steps 1-5 are part of the first event. 6-7 are part of the second event.

A cool thing about JavaScript is that in your callback you still have access to anything *above* it (like the variable `quiz`) because of scoping. This is called a **closure**. Your callback function closes around the scope and brings it with him to the next event.

Answer (score 1):

AJAX calls are asynchronous, you should wait for the result to come back from the server. Either do all the work in a callback function or have a look on a promises library (I like [Q promises](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) library), which makes waiting for AJAX results very easy.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the asynchronous nature of JavaScript, once you call `startQuiz()` it executes and jumps back out and executes your quiz alert().

You have to access your quiz data explicitly after the callback is called to make sure you have access to it.

You also have to worry about scoping, as you may not be actually modifying the same quiz variable.

```
var quiz,
 fetched = false;
$.ajax({
  //blah
 success : function(data){
 fetched = true;
 quiz = data;
}
});

setInterval(function(){
 if(fetched){
 //quiz is populated
  }else{
 //quiz hasn't be populated yet
  }
},50);
```

Although not a clever example, I'm just trying to get the point across that `startQuiz()` doesn't wait for the ajax call. The **A** in AJAX mean asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

You should give jQuery deferreds a try which ist the preferred way of writing ajax related code since jQuery 1.5: http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2012/04/jquery-deferreds-tutorial

Once you get the hang of it maybe will be easier to write and understand your code.